# Is there any way that we can do Profiling on MongoDB in Azure?

Tags: mongodb, azure

[image]Please help me with it, is there any way that we can set Profiling Level on MongoDB in Azure?

When trying to connect from Command Prompt it says connecting but never connects.
and when trying to set profiling level using RoboMongo it is throwing some kind of exception.Will azure allow us to set Profiling?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can log to the mongoshell using:
`mongo MONGO_URL:MONGO_PORT/dbname -u dbuser -p dbpassword`

And then you can set the profiler level using:
`db.setProfilingLevel(PROFILING_LEVEL)`

Comment: I'm trying to set using robomongo, it says failed to execute the script. I'm I missing something?

Comment: What error did you get ? If robomongo fails, try doing it directly from the command line, it might give you more information about why it failed.

Comment: attached screenshots by editing question. Please let me know if I'm missing something? Thank you.

Comment: Your command is correct, I think the problem come from the fact Azure is using a shared database, and sadly the db.setProfilingLevel doesn't work through mongos. You will have to access each shard and run the same db.setProfilingLevel commands in each of their mongo shell.

But frankly I doubt Azure give you access to the mongo shell on each shard. I think you will have to contact Azure directly